# Django: django.db.utils.InternalError: (1046, u'No database selected')

Tags: python, mysql, django, web-applications

I'm trying to use Django with mariadb 10.4.8
My settings.py file is as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME:': 'mydb',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'staff',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

In **init**.py:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

"./manage.py makemigrations" and "./manage.py migrate" yield the same error:

```
    File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 210, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 55, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 50, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 56, in get_table_list
    cursor.execute("SHOW FULL TABLES")
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wemu_app/wemu_app_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1046, u'No database selected')
```

Before anyone asks, yes I am sure the database exists and the user has privledges to to it. I can confirm this with:

```
mysql -u staff -r mydb
```

I'm using the tutorial found here in case anyone is curious:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Any ideas? I'm tearing my hair out here.

Comment: @why port is not added . every dataabase server except sqlite runs on some port

Comment: Originally had it running on 3306, a thread I found suggested leaving it blank as a fix to my problem. Needless to say it didn't work.

Comment: this is strange .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a `MySQL` backend engine to connect to `MariaDB`.

`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',`

Official support for MariaDB was recently added in Django 3.0. It's still in Alpha testing though.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.0/

I think you're better off using a MySQL database to avoid further problems.

Comment: I see, I assumed MySQL and MariaDB interchangeably. Thank you for the link, very helpful.